# cannot update this.state.mostVoted

Tags: reactjs

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          selected: 0,
          votes: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          mostVoted: 0
      }
  }

  updateMostVoted = () => {
      let index = this.state.mostVoted
      const votes = this.state.votes
      for (let i = 0; i < votes.length; i++) {
          if (votes[i] > votes[index]) {
              index = i
          }
      }
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
          mostVoted: index
      }))
      console.log(index)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all. setState is async so when you console.log you need to do it in function after this setState. Something like this:

```js
this.setState(
  {
    mostVoted: index
  },
  () => {
    console.log(this.state.mostVoted);
  }
);
```

Maybe you can give us more information on what you want to do cause your votes array are zeros and mostVoted is zero too.

So yeah we need more infomation.

Comment: I'm doing an anecdote app: https://github.com/Blomqma/Full-stack-open-2018/blob/master/osa1/anekdootit/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

See below for an `updateMostVoted` solution using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Note that the point of using the updater function form of [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is to reference `state` directly when performing calculations, rather than via `this.state`, which can potentially lead to bugs (outlined in the documentation).

```js
// Generate Array.
const generateArray = () => Array.from({length: 10}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))

// Application.
class Application extends React.Component {
  
  // State.
  state = {
    mostVoted: false,
    selected: 0,
    votes: generateArray()
  }
  
  // Render.
  render() {
    const {mostVoted, votes} = this.state
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>Votes: {votes.join(', ')}</div>
        <br/>
        Most Voted 
        <div>Index: {mostVoted}</div>
        <div>Votes: {votes[mostVoted]}</div>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.generateVotes}>Generate Votes</button>
        <button onClick={this.updateMostVoted}>Update Most Voted</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
  
  // Did Mount.
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateMostVoted()
  }
  
  // Generate Votes Array.
  generateVotes = () => this.setState({mostVoted: false, votes: generateArray()})
  
  // Update Most Voted.
  updateMostVoted = () => this.setState(state => {
    const {votes} = this.state
    const {mostVoted} = votes.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
      if (x >= acc.value) return {mostVoted: i, value: x}
      return acc
    }, {mostVoted: 0, value: 0})
    return {mostVoted, votes}
  })
  
}

// Mount.
ReactDOM.render(<Application/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```